# how to make a restful service by using EJB?

Tags: java, entity-framework

I have three tables in my data base , which are related together.
I created entity from table and session ejb bean /
the part of entity code:
entity : Categories

```
private integer CatId;
privete string CatName ;
...
private List<CategoryAttribute> CatAttList;
private List<Products> ProductList;
//getters and setters
```

entity : Products

```
private integer ProId;
private string ProName;
...
private Categories categories
// getters and setters
```

Entity : CategoryAttribute

```
private integer CatAttId;
private string CatAttName ;
...
private Categories categories;
//getters and setters
```

Can I access to fields and value of two table of Products and CategoryAtteribute by using the function" `public List<Products> getProductList()`" and " `public List <CategoryAtteribute> getCatAttList()`" ?(without search in tables because I have a lot of datas in my tables) how?

each Category has many CategoryAtteribute and Product.